# What's better to use arrays or lists to create a multiplication calculator

Tags: java

I'm making a calculator for multiplication. I want it to show each step like we do for long term multiplication. For example:
Long Multiplication

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aor6h.png]

To do this I need to take apart the number digit by digit, which is better for this, lists or arrays?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a pretty general question... why not try one, and see how it goes?

Comment: In concurrence with @Rich, the problem you propose could be solved in many ways - a quality that will probably get this question closed (we don't really like non-specific questions here). So go ahead and try one of the ways you came up with! If you run into a problem along the way, then we're here to help.

Comment: The answer is that either arrays of lists will work, but you can't objectively say which is better until you have implemented both versions and compared them.  I suspect that there is probably little difference.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you want an array when you need to quickly look at any single element of data (like, "I want the 4th digit"). You'll want a list if you're going to keep the data in the same order, and will not need to look up elements at random locations in your set of elements.

The behavior of lists and arrays will vary depending on programming language, but conceptually they derive from these low-level ideas: an array is a contiguous block of memory (that is, memory that's all clumped together). You can read all of the elements in an array by counting indexes -- you start somewhere (say, position 0), then add one to get the next element. It's fast and easy for the computer, but the computer's operating system has to do more work to ensure you have a contiguous block. A list is a way of organizing related data by storing an element of data, along with the location of the next element in the list. You retrieve data by looking at an element, then following the address to the next element, until you get to the end of the list. This makes it easier to structure the data (your pointers to 'next' describe how elements are related) and the operating system and programming language have more flexibility in how to get your program the memory it needs -- but the trade off is that finding any individual element requires you to "walk" the list (follow the pointers.)

All of that is general guidance however; use caution when asking this question in different programming languages and runtime environments, because different environments might call something an array when it's really a list, or vice-verse.

The short answer is: "it depends, but usually you'll use lists if you want to read things in order and use arrays if you want to read elements at random."